# Pending edits error message not being displayed in the review queues

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

On Serverfault:

If you try to edit a message in a review queue (Review First Posts for example) and you have too many pending edits, the error message

```
"You have too many pending edits [...]"
```

won't show up, nothing happens (tested with Chrome/Edge/Firefox)